# UE4. Widget component doesn't show up when its outer is controller

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

As it's said, in UE 4.27 widget component doesn't show up when its outer is player controller. But in 4.18 version it worked.

Could you please explain why ?

And how ( if it's possible ) can I make it work in 4.27 ?

Widget is set in the widget component.

**To reproduce:**

.h:

```
UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly)
TSubclassOf<UComicFXWidgetComponent> ComicWidgetClass;

UComicFXWidgetComponent* NewComponent;
```

My .cpp code that **does work**:

"BeginPlay":

```
// If I change "this" with PlayerController ref then it will not work
NewComponent = NewObject<UComicFXWidgetComponent>(this, ComicWidgetClass);
NewComponent->RegisterComponent();
```

"InteractButtonPressed":

```
NewComponent->AttachToComponent(equippedWeapon_->mesh_, FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale, TEXT("DamageSocket"));
```

My .cpp code that **does NOT work**:

"BeginPlay":

```
APlayerController* PC = UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerController(this, 0);
NewComponent = NewObject<UComicFXWidgetComponent>(PC, ComicWidgetClass); // "this" replaced with "PC"
NewComponent->RegisterComponent();
```

"InteractButtonPressed":

```
NewComponent->AttachToComponent(equippedWeapon_->mesh_, FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale, TEXT("DamageSocket"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. The answer is:

APlayerController derives from AController. And AController in it's constructor calls `SetHidden(true);` and it affects it's children ( or actors whose outer is the controller ).

To solve just add in your Controller constructor:

```
SetActorHiddenInGame(false);
```